# Controller returns a list of data instead of single item, how to solve this issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

**Background**

Recently I changed jobs and attached to a Web API project. I am familiar with the concepts of Web API & MVC but have no prior hands-on experince.

I have followed few tutorials and based on them created an empty WebApi project via Visual Studio 2017, hooked up my model from Database and added Controllers.

This is the revised controller:

```
    private MyEntities db = new MyEntities();
    //...
    [ResponseType(typeof(MyEntityType))]
    [Route("api/MyEntity")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetMyEntityType([FromUri]int parameter)
    {
        MyEntityType found = db.MyEntity
            .OrderByDescending(c => c.CreationTime)
            .First(c => c.ParameterColumn == parameter);


        if (found == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(found );
    }
```

**Note : I am querying based on a column other than KEY**

When I make a call to `.../api/MyEntity?parameter=1` I expect to receive a single item in response. But for reasons unknown to me, the previous call returns all items and it is unsorted.

Please note: If I place a breakpoint on `if (found == null)`, I can confirm that my query has resulted in a single item.

**Question**

What am I missing here? Why does the response contains all elements instead of single element?

**UPDATE 1**

I tried the same call from Postman, this is the output. Please note that I have changed the request, controller code etc. in question to omit some private details.

[image]

I can see that response contains my desired data, but along with all of inner data in other end of relationship. If I am not mistaken, by default, EF uses lazy loading. Since I have no `Include` clause, I have no idea why all related data is returned in response.

I think I need to investigate my relationships in Model/DB and make sure Lazy-Loading is enabled.

**UPDATE 2**

These are my entity classes:

```
public partial class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ForeignKey_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> MyValue { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreationTime { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Some_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual MyOtherEntity MyOtherEntity { get; set; }
}

public partial class MyOtherEntity
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public MyOtherEntity()
    {
        this.MyOtherEntity1 = new HashSet<MyOtherEntity>();
    }

    //...

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<MyOtherEntity> MyOtherEntity1 { get; set; }
    public virtual MyOtherEntity MyOtherEntity2 { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<MyEntity> MyEntity { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It appears that the code you've shown is not being hit by your request. Check for another similar function that returns the entire list and include that in your question.

Comment: Can you post in your question, how you're calling this method?  I don't see, with what you've posted, how you're getting a list returned.

Comment: Yeah this all looks fine to me too. Can we see how the client is calling your API?

Comment: @KirkLarkin I explained in the question: I can confirm that this method is being used.

Comment: @GTown-Coder I am using `Chrome script debugging in Visual Studio` with local IIS to call. This the the complete Uri of call `http://localhost:XXX/api/MyEntity?parameter=1`

Comment: @raidensan Please post your ajax in your question.

Comment: Show the api response, which you are getting

Comment: Sure, something somewhere is hitting your code, but the idea that you return a single entity to the Web Api process, which in turn then goes and gets the entire list from the database is... well... unlikely.

Comment: @KirkLarkin please see the update section of question.

Comment: So `DeviceData` = `MyEntity` and `deviceId` = `parameter`?

Comment: @GTown-Coder correct, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: No inconveniece.. I'm sure we all can respect that some/most developers don't want private data out on the web :)  So, Postman is returning what you're expecting?

Comment: @GTown-Coder Yes. I just need to get rid of other data somehow. Of course I didn't realize that my data actually is in the raw response I saw in Chrome. Postman just made it easier to see it.

Comment: Lazy Loading being enabled sounds like your *problem* not your solution.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Can you elaborate? What have I missed?

Comment: @raidensan Can you show code for the entity class you are trying to return?  I'm specifically interested in the navigation properties.

Comment: @BradleyUffner please see the update 2 section of answer

Comment: @raidensan  I always explicitly turn *off* lazy loading, so that unintentional enumeration throws an error instead of causing large amounts of unneeded data to be returned.  It has saved me from many potential problems, and the slight cost of having to explicitly `.Include` navigation properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the MyEntityType instance is returned via `Ok` it will be converted to JSON which will read the values of all the public properties and fields. This will cause EF to load the entire entity and all relationships. If you only require specific properties to be returned then use Select() as below.

```
var found = db.MyEntity
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.CreationTime)
    .Select(c => new { c.CreationTime, c.ParameterColumn })
    .First(c => c.ParameterColumn == parameter);
```

You can tailor the selected properties as required. If you require criteria in First() that does not need to be selected, move the condition into a Where() call before the Select.

```
var found = db.MyEntity
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.CreationTime)
    .Where(c => c.ParameterColumn == parameter)
    .Select(c => new { c.CreationTime })
    .First();
```

You should probably create a ViewModel of MyEntityType that has only the properties you require, and map these to a new instance of the ViewModel instead. You can then update the `[ResponseType(typeof(MyEntityType))]` attribute too.

For example, declare:

```
public class MyEntityTypeViewModel {
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
    public int ParameterColumn { get; set; }
}
```

And then in your controller action:

```
MyEntityTypeViewModel found = db.MyEntity
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.CreationTime)
    .Where(c => c.ParameterColumn == parameter)
    .Select(c => new MyEntityTypeViewModel { 
        CreationTime = c.CreationTime,
        ParameterColumn = c.ParameterColumn })
    .First();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Entity Framework Core 2, try this:

```
 MyEntityType found = await db.MyEntity.AsNoTracking()
     .OrderByDescending(c => c.CreationTime)
     .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.ParameterColumn == parameter);
```

And it's better to include database context via Dependency Injection, not with private field.